# Building initial module for 4.15.0-28-generic hangs out

Tags: package-management, upgrade, kernel, 18.04, dpkg

During proceeding upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04, process of Building initial module was accidentally interrupted and killed. After that, when I tried to reboot the system it stucks at blank purple screen, and if I try to perform `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo dpkg --configure -a -D1` the whole process stops at the point when line `Building initial module for 4.15.0-28-generic` is displayed.

I've tried to interrupt this process with both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> + <kbd>-></kbd>, however none of them had any effect.

I've also noticed, that part with `sudo dpkg --configure -a -D1` is necessary, as some command claim dpkg contains errors.

P.S. If any piece of information is required to help you in resolving please let me know - this is my very first post here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it turns out to be a problem related to virtualbox and its packages, If anyone is struggling here is the link which helped me:

[Helpful link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2393436)